# UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication for Mono

Tags: asp.net, oauth, mono, owin

I'm trying to use Active Directory Bearer Authentication running on Mono in Owin using Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory package....but apparently Mono System.IdentityModel dll has not implemented System.IdentityModel.Metadata classes which are required by the internal class WsFedMetadataRetriever (http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.5&profile=4.5&assembly=System.IdentityModel).

I tried copying the .NET dll System.IdentityModel to my bin directory when running Mono, but then I get an error "Invalid IL code at System.IdentityModel.Metadata.MetadataSerializer:.ctor"...so that's no good.

Considering this is really just OAuth 2.0 (and I have JavaScript code working that gets a bearer auth token without having to call any unmanaged code, dllimports, or pinvokes), I should be able to make my server side code work on Mono without any significant problem...

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the statement "it's just oauth" hides many details that are instead relevant to the logic at hand. Here you are not getting a token for accessing an existing API, which is the easy part, you are building that API. Oauth alone does not tell you how to validate access tokens, what format access tokens should be in or from where to retrieve the parameters that determine whether a token is valid (signature verification keys and the like). The middleware you are working with does all of those additional things, relying on low level components, such as classes that can parse and verify JWT tokens. AFAIK such classes, and the classes those rely upon, aren't (yet?) available outside of the classic .net framework. Hence, I don't believe that as of today you are going to be able to run that middleware as is on mono.

Comment: Is there a way you can think of to verify the bearer token myself with my own code?

Comment: You'd have to provide logic for performing http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/03/03/principles-of-token-validation/ - with the jwt format it is doable, but it is substantial work with delicate security implications. I expect those classes to eventually become available cross platform, at which point they'll just work without extra work required of you... But we're not there yet.